# Call WebService different WebApplication returns 401

Tags: 2013, web-services

I am trying to access a WebService from some JQuery code in WebApplication1. In WebApplication1 I am authenticated as alvmad user. When I try to access to the SharePoint Lists.asmx webservice of MySite (WebApp 2) I am receiving a 401 unauthorized.
This is the code I am using from `http://sp2013:9090:`

```
var url1 = "http://sp2013:81/personal/alvmad/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
var libraryName = "Testing";

function processResult(xData, status)
{
$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
alert(liHtml);
    });
}

var soapPacket = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
<soapenv:Body> \
<GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
<listName>"+ libraryName + "</listName> \
<viewFields> \
<ViewFields> \
<FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
</ViewFields> \
</viewFields> \
</GetListItems> \
</soapenv:Body> \
</soapenv:Envelope>";
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapPacket,
    complete: processResult,
    error:function(){alert("error");},
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});
```

We cannot change the authentication mode to Kerberos. We have NTLM.

**UPDATE**

I finally deployed an Application Page with GAC deployment. That page is called from AJAX JQuery and the logic is server side. Question closed

Comment: of course the first question is: have you check if the user is authorize on the second web site?

Comment: Of course. If I access through the browser I enter my personal site in SharePoint 2013